# Craft 3.1 Beta - Email settings and categories not working

Tags: craft3, admin

I'm getting an "UnexpectedValueException" on the pages /admin/settings/categories/new and /admin/settings/email after updating to the beta.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause: Moved the template folder from / to /src/
This also apparently affect the backend / admin templates for some reason.

Solution: Update index.php to use the right path.

[image]